# showing progressdialog in activitygroup

Tags: android, progressdialog, activitygroup

How can I use a `ProgressDialog` in an `ActivityGroup`? I want to show a `ProgressDialog` when a user is touching on a button and I want to hide that dialog when all the loading is done in the next `Activity`.

I've created two functions in the `ActivityGroup`....

```
public void showSpinner()
{
    mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(group);    
    mSpinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mSpinner.setMessage("Loading...");
    mSpinner.show();
}


public void hideSpinner()
{
    mSpinner.dismiss();
}
```

I'm calling this function before I'm replacing the `Activity`, see the code below:

```
TestAppgroup.showSpinner();

Intent intent = new Intent(Start.this, CitySelect.class);
View view = TestAppgroup.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("cityselect", intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();               
TestAppgroup.replaceView(view);
```

This works only for 50%. It does show the `ProgressDialog`, but only when the next `Activity` is loaded. What I want is that the `ProgressDialog` will show when the user clicks the button...

Any help on this please?